# service-activator or listener-container

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

I am using Spring AMQP and Spring Integration.  I am currently using a service-activator from integration as my handler.  I have tried to get an amqp listener working as well but I never receive the message.  Is using a service-activator accepted practice or should I be using a listener?

```
<!-- Receive Inbound messages and process them -->
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="sda.text.analytics.process.channel" queue-names="${sda.text.analytics.process.queue}"
    connection-factory="sda.text.analytics.connectionFactory" prefetch-count="${sda.mule.prefetchCount}"
    concurrent-consumers="${uima.process.threads}" task-executor="analyticsExecutor" receive-timeout="5000"/>

<int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="sda.text.analytics.process.channel" type="com.issinc.sda.ingest.impl.IngestBean"/>

<bean id="analyticsExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="${uima.process.threads}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${uima.process.threads}" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="${sda.mule.prefetchCount}" />
</bean>

<!-- Service that listens for an inbound messages, processes the text and sends the processed text back -->
<int:service-activator input-channel="sda.text.analytics.process.channel" output-channel="sda.text.analytics.response.channel"
   ref="asyncExtractionService" method="processMessage" >
</int:service-activator>
<!--<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="sda.connectionFactory" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter">
    <rabbit:listener ref="asyncExtractionService" method="processMessage" queue-names="${sda.process.queue}" />
</rabbit:listener-container>-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not really "using" the service activator at all; you are invoking the same bean/method as the service activator.

Consider using an AMQP inbound channel adapter to send messages to the service activator via the `sda.process.channel`.

Comment: Thanks Gary.  I have a channel-adapter:
    <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="sda.process.channel" queue-names="${sda.process.queue}"
        connection-factory="sda.connectionFactory" prefetch-count="${sda.mule.prefetchCount}"
        concurrent-consumers="${process.threads}" task-executor="analyticsExecutor" receive-timeout="5000"/>

Comment: As you can see, code/config doesn't render well in comments here. It's better to edit your question. Do you have messages in the queue? Are your properties correct? Generally, turning on debug logging will provide enough information to debug issues like this.

Comment: You should also take a look at the [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/amqp).

Comment: Thanks Gary, I have seen the samples and read the docs.  I am still a bit unclear about a few things.  My service-activator is working.  I should have been more clear.  My real question is if it is correct to use a service-activator, if I should be using a listener-container instead, or if it doesn't matter?

Comment: It really depends on you requirements. Spring Integration is a higher level abstraction that allows you to loosely couple components together with messaging. If all you want to do is invoke some POJO for each message, and do nothing else then you don't really need Spring Integration at all. But if you want the flexibility to add filters, transformers etc before invoking the POJO, even if later on down the road, then SI is the way to go.